# Custom RuleFilter when filtering a message with Azure Service Bus

Tags: filter, azureservicebus, messaging, azure-servicebus-topics

Let's suppose I've a `topic` in ***Azure Service Bus*** and this topic receives all the products registered in my application. So, at the end of the day, the body of the message will the serialization of this struct:

```
public struct Product
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public decimal Price {get: set;}
   public DateTime LastOrder {get: set;} 
}
```

My question is can I implement my own `RuleFilter` and not rely on the ones provided by the framework such as `SqlRuleFilter` and `CorrelationRuleFilter`?
I would like to use lambda and do something like that to subscribe for example to the expensive products:

```
var ruleOptions = new CreateRuleOptions("Default", new ConditionalRule(prod => prod.Price > 1000.00));
```

I'm trying to create my own `ConditionalRule` which inherit from the `RuleFilter` class but I fear that this would not be enough.

Example of the class that I would like to implement:

```
internal class ConditionalFilter<T> : RuleFilter
{
    private readonly Func<bool, T> _rule;

    public ConditionalFilter(Func<bool, T> rule)
    {
        _rule = rule ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rule));
    }

    public override bool Equals(RuleFilter other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal override RuleFilter Clone()
    {
        return new ConditionalFilter<T>(_rule);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, it's only possible with `CreateRuleOptions` which uses `SqlRuleFilter` and `CorrelationRuleFilter`. [Sevice Bus - Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples) and [Is there a way to define a Azure Service Bus rule/filter when setting up a consumer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507697/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-azure-service-bus-rule-filter-when-setting-up-a-consu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I implement my own `RuleFilter` and not rely on the ones provided by the framework such as `SqlRuleFilter` and `CorrelationRuleFilter`

No, you cannot. If you want messages to be filtered, you'll have to

1. Use `CorrelationRuleFilter` or `SqlRuleFilter` (most likely the latter)
2. Promote values from the payload/body to headers